# Response renders only half of the HTML

Tags: java

I am having a large HTML content in a String and I am trying to render it to the browser using output stream of response and also response getWriter method, but only half of the content is getting rendered when I checked the view source.

I used this following code,

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Encoding","utf-8");
                resp.getWriter().println(htmlSourceToRender);
                resp.getWriter().flush();
```

Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: Did you close the writer?

Comment: No I will try to close

Comment: I tried with close, still I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I checked the String which I am trying to render, It is a valid HTML content